# Помогите написать это на jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var tetrisDom = document.getElementById(Tetris.config.pitchID);

tetrisDom.innerHTML = '';

for (var i = 0; i < Tetris.pitch.bricks.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < Tetris.pitch.bricks[i].length; j++) {

       tetrisDom.innerHTML += Tetris.pitch.bricks[i][j]
                     ? Tetris.config.filledBrick
                     : Tetris.config.freeBrick;
  }
 }
```

Comment: а в чем смысл переписывать этот код на jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tetrisDom = $('#'+Tetris.config.pitchID);

tetrisDom.empty();

for (var i = 0; i < Tetris.pitch.bricks.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < Tetris.pitch.bricks[i].length; j++) {
       tetrisDom.append(Tetris.pitch.bricks[i][j] ? $(Tetris.config.filledBrick) : $(Tetris.config.freeBrick));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так.
Не проверял.

```
var tetrisDom = $('#' + Tetris.config.pitchID);

tetrisDom.html('');

for (var i = 0; i < Tetris.pitch.bricks.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < Tetris.pitch.bricks[i].length; j++) {

       tetrisDom.html( tetrisDom.html() + Tetris.pitch.bricks[i][j]
                     ? Tetris.config.filledBrick
                     : Tetris.config.freeBrick );
  }
 }
```